# Не работают мета поля в function WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На странице вывожу с помощью цикла записи и подгружаю их ajaxом. Но то, какое форматирование записи происходит в цикле в зависимости от содержания произвольных полей к каждой из этих записей, абсолютно не работает для тех постов, которые подгружены ajaxом.

По сути: В зависимости от количества изображений прикрепленных к записи ( все картинки находятся в произвольном поле) формируется визуальный блок записи через if. Как сделать так, чтобы все условия работали. Предполагаю, что моя $img почему-то не срабатывает и далее, как следствие, не срабатывает ни одно условие, отвечающее за преобразование внешнего вида поста.

Мои коды:
Скрипт jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
    $(this).text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
    var data = {
        'action': 'loadmore',
        'query': true_posts,
        'page' : current_page
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:ajaxurl, // обработчик
        data:data, // данные
        type:'POST', // тип запроса
        success:function(data){
            if( data ) { 
                $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
                current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
            } else {
                $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Теперь то, что я вызываю в function.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'true_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loadmore.js', array('jquery') );


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_loadmore_scripts' );

function true_load_posts(){
    $args = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['query']));
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // следующая страница
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $q->have_posts() ):
        while($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();
     $GLOBALS['current_id'] = $post->ID;

            ?>
<? $img1 = get_post_meta($GLOBALS['current_id'], 'image_upload_3035707669', true); ?>
            <div  class="col-lg-11 shadow-sm mtop20 m20 bfff" id="post-<?php echo $postid; ?>"  >
   <div class="row">

       <?php $img1 = get_post_meta($GLOBALS['current_id'], 'image_upload_3035707669', true); ?>

   <? if ($img1 !== '' and $img1 >=2) {echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-12 g0065"  style="background:url(' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $img1, 'full' ) . '); background-size:cover; background-position:center; border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;">

   <a href="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url( $img1, 'full' ).'" rel="lightbox" class="h02754"></a>
   </div>';} ?>


<div class=" <? if ($img1 !== '' and $img1 >= 1) {echo 'col-lg-8';} else {echo 'col-lg-12';} ?>">
<div class="row ptop10">

<div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"> <div class="h80777" ><i class="fal fa-user"></i></div></div>
<div class="col-8 ">
    <div style="display: none;"> <? $autor = the_author(); ?></div>
<div class="col-12 h2015" ><? if ($autor == '') {echo '<i class="h0714">анонимный пост</i>';} else { the_author();} ?></div>
<div class="col-12 g20555"><i class="fal fa-clock iconpr5"></i><?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?> <i class="far fa-eye iconpr5 iconpl10"></i> <? echo pvc_get_post_views() ?></div>
</div>
<div class="col-2 f502">


</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 mtop20 mbottom10 h20251">
    <?  $cont = get_the_content();  

while ( mb_strpos($cont,' ')!==false )
    {
    $cont = str_replace(' ','',$cont);
    }; 

$cont = mb_strlen(strip_tags($cont));

?>
    <? if ($cont < 100 and $img1 == '' ) { echo '<p class="singleposttext">' . get_the_content() . '</p>'; } else { echo '<p class="singleposttextfull">' . get_the_content() . '</p>';}  ?>



    <div class="row">
        <? if ($img1 <= 3 ) { ?>
<?  $grabMeta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_upload_3035707669', true );

$myvalues = unserialize( $grabMeta );

foreach ( $myvalues as $myvalue ) { 
    echo '<div class="col"><a rel="lightbox" href="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $myvalue, 'full' ) .'"><img class="h909045" style="width:100%;" src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $myvalue,'prewpostbig' ) .' " /></a></div>';
} ?>
        <? }
        else { $grabMeta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_upload_3035707669', true );

$myvalues = unserialize( $grabMeta );

foreach ( $myvalues as $myvalue ) { 
    echo '<div class="col"><a rel="lightbox" href="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $myvalue, 'full' ) .'"><img class="h909045"  src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $myvalue, 'prewpostsmall' ) .' " /></a></div>';
}   }



        ?>
        </div>





 </div>
 </div>
<div class="row justify-content-between">
<div class="col-4 p20"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i> <?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?> </a><i class="fal fa-bookmark s201"></i></div>
  <div class="col-4 p20 text-right"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[wp_ulike]' ); ?></div>
</div>
   </div>
   </div>



   </div> 

            <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_postss');
```

И то, чем я вызываю все это действие на главной странице

```
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
 <script>
 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
 var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
 var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
 var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
 </script>
<div class="more_block"><div class="btn_more_blocks" id="true_loadmore">Показать больше материалов</div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил путем добавления global $post в функцию true_load_posts() в файле function.php